# index column on varchar not working

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have index column 'unique_identifier'. When I fetch data using index column it is not getting fetched using index.

```
    mysql> show index from stock_index_table;
    +-------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table             | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +-------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | stock_index_table |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | id                | A         |        4393 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | stock_index_table |          1 | unique_identifier |            1 | unique_identifier | A         |        4393 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

When check using 'explain extended' it showing 'using where' instead of 'using index'. Is it means data not getting fetched using index column ? Below is result of 'explain extended' for select query.

```
    mysql> explain extended select id 
       from stock_index_table
       where unique_identifier='Nifty' ;
    +----+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
    +----+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | stock_index_table | ref  | unique_identifier | unique_identifier | 52      | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
    +----+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Result for 'explain' should look like this in Extra.

```
    +--------------------------+
    | Extra                    |
    +--------------------------+
    | Using index              |
    +--------------------------+
```

Comment: You may find it helpful to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: Is there an actual **problem** here or is it just that it bothers you that index is not being used? Is your query slow?

Comment: PLEASE provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not confuse things by naming a *non-unique* index "unique..."!

The `EXPLAIN` looks optimal.

"Using index" (meaning "covering") says that only the index was needed.  You have

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(unique_identifier)
```

and you *appear* to be using InnoDB.  This means that the index is really `(unique_identifier, id)` since (in InnoDB), the PK is silently added to any secondary index.

Since the query only needs those two columns, it is "covering".

Since the column is assumed to show up more than once, it needs to be "ref" and "using where".  The "Rows=1" is simply because the statistics have deduced that the column is pretty close to unique.

The execution will

- Drill down the B+Tree for the index to locate the *first* occurrence of "Nifty"
- Scan forward (this is efficient in a B+Tree that InnoDB uses) until it finds an entry that is not "Nifty".

So, it will touch one extra 'row' in the index.  If it had been `UNIQUE`, it would not need to scan ahead.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to the query optimizer as to how it fetches the data, it may be that for a small table, all indexes are ignored.
It can also be that your query isn't suitable, we would have to be able to see the table and query to see if there is something else that can be done.